# elasticsearch size parameter not work

Tags: elasticsearch

With size parameter or not this query always return 10 document(total doc:12678)
Somehow it ignores size parameter, even size eqauls to 2 it returns 10 docs again

```
POST webproxylog/_search
    {
      "from": 0, "size": 100, 
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
             "terms": {
                "category": [

                  "-1",
                  "0"
                ]
              }
          }
        }
      },
      "sort": [
        {
          "respsize": {
            "order": "desc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use POST instead of GET when sending the query in the HTTP payload. Some HTTP clients do not send a payload when using GET.

The following will get you 100 results:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/webproxylog/_search -d '{
      "from": 0, "size": 100, 
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
             "terms": {
                "category": [

                  "-1",
                  "0"
                ]
              }
          }
        }
      },
      "sort": [
        {
          "respsize": {
            "order": "desc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }'
```

Comment: any configuration required to make 'size' process works in elasticsearch ?

Comment: but I set size to 2, it returns 10 doc again

Comment: Hello again valentin how re you :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020078/ordering-by-aggregration-result-value can you check this :D

Comment: Long time no see :) can you check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232642/elasticsearch-update-existing-field-data-of-documents Thank you

Comment: Size parameter works in Dev tools section but not in the filter of discover section.

Comment: @deenaik filters in the discover section are just that, i.e. filters, there's no reason to put a size in there.

Comment: Thanks, I am saving those filters to be used in the dashboard, there I need to limit the records.