# Ordering term aggregation buckets by sub-aggregration result values

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I have two questions about the query seen on this capture:

1. How do I order by `value` in the `sum_category` field in the results?
   I use `respsize` again in the query but it's not correct as you can see below.
2. Even if I make only an aggregration, why do all the documents come with the result? I mean, if I make a `group by` query in SQL it retrieves only grouped data, but Elasticsearch retrieves all documents as if I made a normal search query. How do I skip them?

[image]

Comment: Please put text/code inline as text rather than an image.

Comment: @philipxy Yes, I will after now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "categories" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "category",
                "size" : 999999,
                "order" : {
                    "sum_category" : "desc"
                }
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "sum_category" : {
                    "sum" : {
                        "field" : "respsize"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1). See the note in (2) for what your `sort` is doing.  As for ordering the categories by the value of sum_category, see the `order` portion.  There appears to be an old and closed issue related to that https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4643 but it worked fine for me with v1.5.2 of Elasticsearch.

2). Although you do not have that match_all query, I think that's probably what you are getting results for.  And so the sort your specified is actually getting applied to those results.  To not get these back, I just have `size: 0` portion.

Do you want buckets for all the categories?  I noticed you do not have size specified for the main aggregation.  That's the `size: 999999` portion.

Comment: damn you gave me more then I need, yes I want all I added size:9999, but is there anything get all buckets instead type size:99999 exmp. size:_all or etc. ?

Comment: No, I do not think there is.